# Adding Facebook Meta tags to dotnetnuke pages

Tags: asp.net, facebook, dotnetnuke, meta-tags, facebook-comments

I have added the Facebook comments plugin to dynamic pages on my site, and I am attempting to set up administration of those plugins by adding the associated meta tags to their pages. My site uses the CMS dotnetnuke.

I went to the page's settings - under advanced - and added the appropriate meta tag information. However, upon saving, administration is not enabled on that page.

I ran the page through the wc3 validator, and the following error related to that meta tag was produced:

> Error Line 11, Column 1926: there is no attribute "property"

```
…type="text/javascript"></script><meta property="fb:admins" content="76804243"/>
```

✉

> You have used the attribute named above in your document, but the
>   document type you are using does not support that attribute for this
>   element. This error is often caused by incorrect use of the "Strict"
>   document type with a document that uses frames (e.g. you must use the
>   "Transitional" document type to get the "target" attribute), or by
>   using vendor proprietary extensions such as "marginheight" (this is
>   usually fixed by using CSS to achieve the desired effect instead).
>
> This error may also result if the element itself is not supported in
>   the document type you are using, as an undefined element will have no
>   supported attributes; in this case, see the element-undefined error
>   message for further information.
>
> How to fix: check the spelling and case of the element and attribute,
>   (Remember XHTML is all lower-case) and/or check that they are both
>   allowed in the chosen document type, and/or use CSS instead of this
>   attribute. If you received this error when using the  element
>   to incorporate flash media in a Web page, see the FAQ item on valid
>   flash.

Do I need to specify this attribute somehow in my DNN skin? Any ideas on a possible fix?

Thanks!
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways you can change the DocType for your site. Here's the entry from the DotNetNuke wiki that describes the options:
http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Wiki/Page/Set-the-doctype-of-your-skin.aspx